# How to locally update repository from github

Tags: github

If I cloned a `github` repository with the follwoing command:

```
git clone - git://github.com/user/project.git
```

And then the developer commits further changes (to the main branch) how can I get the latest changes locally?

Answer (score 3):

[git pull](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-pull.html)
Also check out [this resoruce](http://ndpsoftware.com/git-cheatsheet.html#loc=local_repo;) for a visual representation of the git commands.

Comment: Interesting link to visual demonstration of git. Excellent for new users of git

Answer (score 1):

A `git pull` will retrieve the changes from the main branch to your local repository